# What are the jars provided by an application server?

Tags: java, gradle, application-server

I am switching my build chain from the one provided by Eclipse to Gradle.
When I develop a web application in Eclipse, I used to add a particular server runtime, so to have the jars provided by the application server already in the classpath.

Now that I am swtiching to Gradle, how do I know what are the jars provided from the application server and which must consequently indicated as *providedCompile* instead of *compile*?

Comment: which application server are you using?

Comment: try no to aim a app server. think in terms of jee-version instead example JEE7, JEE7 web profile seems to be the same thing, but while the first can be satisfied by wildfly, glassfish or websphere, tomcat doesn't. tomcat and jetty only can handle the web profile.

Comment: @p-s-m in the specific case I am using JBoss. I know that I can see the provided jars in the modules subfolder of my jboss local installation. What I was wandering is whether there is a repository or anything addressable by Gradle which adds all the dependencies provided by jboss, something like: providedCompile 'org.jboss.providedlibs:7.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. in essence, you'll need the 'war' gradle plugin: https://gesellix.net/providedcompile-and-compile-dependencies-with-gradle/

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on your app server: they all come with different JARs (obviously stuff like Servlet etc being provided by all)

You could remove the Server Runtime from your Eclipse classpath and see what breaks?

Comment: Yes... that's exactly the approach I was using, but it seems to me a bit ...... dirty?

Comment: I felt dirty when suggesting it TBH. You could JVM option -verbose:class? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbmtm

Comment: Mm... I see... it seems there is no answer to my question. Anybody who wants to land a hand and create several empty jars containing only the provided libs of the various application servers and upload them on mavencentral/jcenter? That'd be nice, huh? So if you want to target a particoular version of a particoulas AS, you indicate this empty jar as a providedCompile dependency. Would that work?